# Can a character have two of the same type of identity card?

Tags: city-of-mist

If a player wants to have two of the same type of identity card, for example two Bastion cards, is that possible as per the rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Possible, but boring.

> Choose four themes for your character from the list of theme types below. Choose at least one Mythos theme and at least one Logos theme. To make your character richer and more interesting, it is recommended not to repeat theme types. Different player characters can choose the same theme type.
>
> -- *City of Mist Player's Guide*, p.65

Also, if you pick Bastion twice, it's not the same exact power that you can always double-kick when it's appropriate. It's a different way your Mythos has of protecting its thematic things.